# ¿Como almacenar varios Entry en una lista?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, entrada

¿Como puedo ingresar los valores de varios Entry distintos, dentro de una misma lista?

- Todos los Entry, están en el mismo Frame hecho con Tkinter.
- Algunos Entry, son texto, y otros son números.
- La lista la voy a utilizar luego, para ejecutar sentencias en SQL.

Adjunto copia del código que llevo hasta el momento

```
from tkinter import *

Ventana2 = Tk()
Ventana2.title("Principal - Ingresar moto")
Ventana2.resizable(1,1)
Ventana2.config(width=300, height=500)

Contenedor3 = Frame()
Contenedor3.pack()
Contenedor3.config(width=300, height=500)
Contenedor3.config(pady=5)

Marca = Label(Contenedor3, text="Marca:")
Marca.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

Modelo = Label(Contenedor3, text="Modelo:")
Modelo.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

Anio = Label(Contenedor3, text="Año:")
Anio.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
#
Tipo = Label(Contenedor3, text="")
Tipo.grid(row=0, column=1)

Marca = Entry(Contenedor3)
Marca.grid(row=1, column=1)

Modelo = Entry(Contenedor3)
Modelo.grid(row=2, column=1)

Anio = Entry(Contenedor3)
Anio.grid(row=3, column=1)

#
Contenedor4 = Frame()
Contenedor4.pack()
Contenedor4.config(width=300, height=500)
Contenedor4.config(pady=10)

BotonGuardar = Button(Contenedor4, text="Guardar")
BotonGuardar.grid(row=0, column=0)

BotonCancelar = Button(Contenedor4, text="Cancelar")
BotonCancelar.grid(row=0, column=1)

Ventana2.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro en que orden querrás registradas en la lista cada una de las cadenas que obtengas de los Entry. De todos modos, una forma sería llamar a una función desde el botón "Guardar", y en la función utilizar el método get() para obtener el contenido de los Entry y el metodo append para insertarlo en la última posición de la lista.

```
def crear_lista():
     lista = []
     lista.append(Marca.get()) # El método append agrega el valor en la última posición.
     lista.append(Modelo.get())
     lista.append(Anio.get())
     return lista

BotonGuardar = Button(Contenedor4, text="Guardar", command=crear_lista) # Agregas el command para llamar a la función
```